# Boost interprocess creating memory mapped file > 4GB

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

When I try to create a memory mapped file using boost interprocess managed_mapped_file of size > 4GB, a smaller file is created (e.g. if a 5GB specification results in a 1GB file).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>

int main()
{
   unsigned int sizeInMB = 4 * 1024 - 1;
   boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file file1(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MyMappedFile1", sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024);
   std::cout << "Free memory File 1 = " << file1.get_segment_manager()->get_free_memory() << std::endl;

   sizeInMB = 5 * 1024;
   boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file file2(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MyMappedFile2", sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024);
   std::cout << "Free memory File 2 = " << file2.get_segment_manager()->get_free_memory() << std::endl;
}
```

The output here is -

```
Free memory File 1 = 4293918496
Free memory File 2 = 1073741600
```

How can I create a file larger than 4 GB?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to create this memory mapped file? We don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Please see code sample above. In the real use case, the size in MB comes from config.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with this library, but is it possible that the size of the memory-mapped file is stored as a 32-bit integer, and you are seeing an integer overflow?

Comment: `sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024` Start by printing this value.

Comment: I know it is an integer overflow that is causing this. But I want to understand if it is possible to create a larger than 4 GB memory mapped file using boost interprocess. Is there any setting for the library that can help OR if not, what are suggested alternatives e.g. chunking?

Comment: The argument is `size_t` type, so it can take large numbers. The problem is in your calculation using `unsigned int`. Use `size_t` as type instead.

Comment: Using std::size_t worked. Thanks @teapot418

Answer (score 0):

The wrapping happens because you use `int`, instead of `size_t`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>

int main()
{
   size_t sizeInMB = 4 * 1024 - 1;
   boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file file1(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MyMappedFile1", sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024);
   std::cout << "Free memory File 1 = " << file1.get_segment_manager()->get_free_memory() << std::endl;

   sizeInMB = 5 * 1024;
   boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file file2(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MyMappedFile2", sizeInMB * 1024 * 1024);
   std::cout << "Free memory File 2 = " << file2.get_segment_manager()->get_free_memory() << std::endl;
}
```

Printing

```
Free memory File 1 = 4293918496
Free memory File 2 = 5368708896
```